# Mobile app installs - get/set ads tags

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-ios-sdk, ads, facebook-ads-api

Is there a way to set a mobile app install ad with the ads tags and then on the app install to get this information via the SDK?

I want to be able to track my ads installs.
Notice that I'm aware that Facebook offers a way to do that via the in-app events way, but they only saves this information on their ends and not revealing this information.
I want to be able to retrieve this information to my system in order to optimize it with my own methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible at present to gain this information through the SDK.

The only way, is to partner with one of Facebook's Mobile Measurement providers. A list can be found here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/preferredmarketingdevelopers/mobile/measurement/